# The skill is rejecting the request when executed with additional properties in the JSON request

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, alexa-skills-kit

I'm having problems when I deploy my alexa skill to google cloud functions.

Initially, I'm using the following code.

My `skill.js` file

```js
//imports here...

  Router.post("/:locale", async (req, res) => {
    const requestEnvelope = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    try {
      await new SkillRequestSignatureVerifier().verify(requestEnvelope, req.headers);
      await new TimestampVerifier().verify(requestEnvelope);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Error with message: ${err.message}`);
      console.log(`Error object: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
      return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    }
    const responseASK = await skill.invoke(req.body);
    return res.status(200).send(responseASK);
  });

module.exports = Router;
```

In my `server.js` file

```js
const skillRoute = require("./skill");

const express = require("express");
const server = express();
server.use("/", skillRoute);

exports.server = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

Everything goes well with the deploy, including, I can invoke my alexa skill normally. But, when running the validations for distribution, I get the following problem:

---

**The skill is rejecting the request when executed with additional properties in the JSON request.**

*When we invoke the skill with additional parameters, the skill is rejecting it when we expect this to be accepted. Future versions of the Alexa Skills Kit may add new properties to the JSON request and response formats, while maintaining backward compatibility for the existing properties. Your code must be resilient to these types of changes. For example, your code for de-serializing a JSON request must not break when it encounters a new, unknown property. Please ensure that your code can handle new attributes and does not break when it encounters new properties in the JSON request.
Documentation Help:
Request and response JSON reference:* [Click here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#cert-verify-signature-certificate-url)

---

On my server console I get the following errors:

`Error with message: request body and signature does not match`

and:

`Error object: {"name":"AskSdk.SkillRequestSignatureVerifier Error"}`

It seems to me that it may be the result of some `ask-sdk-core` update, as I have other servers working with the same code.